# Sql Server: Calculate data by each month,year and Group by something

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, select

First of all, my table structure is something similar like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Testing(
       [ID]        NVARCHAR(50),
       [DATE]      DATETIME,
       [TOTAL]     INT,
       [ITEM]      NVARCHAR(50),
       [Warehouse] NVARCHAR(50)
)ON[PRIMARY]
```

I put some sample here:

```
[ID] [Date]      [Total] [Item] [Warehouse]
1    2011-04-04  400     A0001   B12
2    2011-05-04  500     A0001   B13
3    2011-04-30  400     A0001   B12
4    2011-04-25  400     A0001   B13
5    2011-06-05  600     A0001   B12
6    2011-03-02  300     A0001   B11
7    2011-05-28  500     A0001   B13
```

I am trying to group by [Item] and [Warehouse] and [Date] by month as well
For example output:

The result should be like this

```
[Date]        [Total]   [Item]  [Warehouse]
March 2011     300       A0001   B11
April 2011     800       A0001   B12
June 2011      500       A0001   B12
April 2011     400       A0001   B13
May 2011       1000      A0001   B13
```

I tried the sql something like, that i parse in month and year part to made the selection

```
SELECT [Item],[Warehouse],SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM [Testing]
WHERE Datepart(month,[Date]) = 4 AND DATEPART(year,[Date]) = 2011
GROUP BY [Item],[Warehouse]
```

I get the expected result?Is there any way to do? i actually trying to came out a close balance for each month and year by distinct of warehouse and item?

Sound to me its need to loop through a prefix table..
Its that anyway to do so?

Thanks

Regards 
Liangck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that formatting date on SQL Server side is (usually) a bed idea, but anyway you can try:

```
select datename(mm, dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, [date]), 0)) + ' ' +
      select cast(datepart(yy, dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, [date]), 0)) as varchar)
      [date] sum(total) as total, item,warehouse
from testing
group by item, warehouse, dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, [date]), 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the following functions

[DATENAME (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) and [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Have a look at the example below

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        DateValue DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '01 Jan 2011'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '01 Feb 2011'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '01 Feb 2011'

SELECT  DATENAME(month,DateValue) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(year,DateValue) AS VARCHAR(4)),
        COUNT(1) TotalCnt
FROM    @Table
GROUP BY DATENAME(month,DateValue) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(year,DateValue) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Results:

```
February 2011   2
January 2011    1
```

Comment: Hello: I think what i wanted is how to select out the data but not change the output.But anyway,yours explanation is helpful..thanks @astander for your time.